# In safari browser not able to download image with html content using html2canvas in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

Iam able to download image with content in chrome using html2canvas package, but in safari iam able to download image but content was not showing/blacked . Using below code for click event
[Safari downloaded image preview][1]

````
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    const captureDOMItemArr: HTMLCollectionOf<any> = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'insight-content'
    );
    const captureDOMItem: HTMLElement = captureDOMItemArr[0];
    function downloadURI(uri: string, name: string) {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = name;
      link.href = uri;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
    html2canvas(captureDOMItem, {
      allowTaint: true,
      foreignObjectRendering: true
    }).then((canvas: any) => {
      const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      downloadURI(img, 'screenshot.png');
    });
  }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n3U7.png
````

Answer (score 0):

There currently is an open issue at GitHub [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2188). There is also an unofficial solution for that problem. But it seems to have no perfect answer.